# Distortion-Rate function for standard Gaussian signals quantized with a uniform alphabet

Tags: digital-communications, quantization, information-theory, compression, distortion

Let's say $X \sim N(0, 1)$ is a standard Gaussian input signal and $Y \sim U\{y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{16}\}$ follows a discrete uniform distribution (in fact, $\{y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_{16}\}$ is a reconstruction alphabet for $X$). Under the MSE distortion measure $d(x, y) = (x - y)^2$, for a given rate $R^* = 2$ (bits, not nats!), I want to find

$$
\begin{aligned}
D(R^*) =& \inf_{p(y|x)} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{16} p(x)p(y_i|x) d(x, y_i) dx \\
& \text{subject to}\; I(X; Y) \le R^*
\end{aligned}.
$$

This is a convex optimization problem, which is generally easy, but here $p(y|x)$ can be an arbitrary continuous distribution so I don't know how to parameterize it. I am aware of [the Blahut–Arimoto algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blahut%E2%80%93Arimoto_algorithm), but it only works when both $X$ and $Y$ are discrete and finite (in which case $p(y|x)$ can be expressed as a table).

Anyway, it sounds like a pretty fundamental problem. Is there a known result about it?

**Background:**

Ultimately, I only care about $p(x|y)$, i.e. the backward test channel that attains the distortion-rate bound. I posed the question as finding $p(y|x)$ since it follows naturally from the definition of $D(R^*)$ and applying the Bayes rule to $p(y|x)$ gives us $p(x|y)$. However, if you can somehow find $p(x|y)$ directly, feel free to post an answer!

**Attempt:**

Since a higher rate can always decrease the distortion, the constraint is essentially $I(X; Y) = R^* = 2$.
It follows that

$$
\begin{aligned}
2 = I(X; Y) =& H(X) - H(X|Y) \\
=& \frac{1}{2}\log_2(2 \pi e \sigma^2) - H(X|Y) \\
H(X|Y) =& \frac{1}{2}\log_2(2 \pi e \sigma^2) - 2
\end{aligned}
$$

and

$$
\begin{aligned}
2 = I(X; Y) =& H(Y) - H(Y|X) \\
=& 4 - H(Y|X) \\
H(Y|X) =& 2
\end{aligned}
$$

However, I have no clue how to proceed.

Comment: Definitely not an expert here, so I won't provide an answer. However, you might want to check out this paper. https://www2.spsc.tugraz.at/www-archive/downloads/Leitinger12_DA.pdf

Comment: Any arbitrary distribution can be modelled as summation of Gaussian.